# Web API 2, CORS, NTLM & OWIN / Katana with Angular 2

Tags: angular, cors, owin, windows-authentication, webapi2

Massive amount of issues getting this to work.

Thought I'd put up the common issues and the solutions having wasted a day on this and being led down many false paths by other answers.

Setup :

1. Web Api 2 Server
2. Server configured for NTLM (Negotiate)
3. Angular website hosted on a different machine or Port
4. Website connects to API to do, well, stuff.

Issues :

1. Basic setup and first time you run it you get `no access-control-allow-origin header is present`
2. Setting Cors on the server and you still get the issue
3. You eventually realise that Angular isn't setting `WithCredentials` on its calls and fix this, now `GET` works but `PUT`, `POST` & `DELETE` fail with something about pre-flights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the solutions :

1. Firstly your server needs to be enabled for cors and this must be the first line in your app config :

   `WebApp.Start(_configuration.Url, app =>
   {
      app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

   2. Enable Authentication, BUT not for the pre-flight `OPTIONS` calls :

   `var listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
   listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate = request => 
      request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS" 
           ? AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous 
           : AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;`

   3. Set your Angular code to send calls in with `WithCredentials`.  There's many different ways to do this, but we used an authentication interceptor :
      `intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
      Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      const authReq = request.clone({ withCredentials: true });
      return next.handle(authReq)`
   4. If you want to do anything fancy for your Auth you can create your own middleware by extending `OwinMiddleware` and overriding the `Invoke` method. This can then be registerd in the pipeline with `app.Use<MyMiddleware>(paramsToConstructor)` in your `override` method you can access the Identity of the user with :

   `var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Authentication.User.Identity.AuthenticationType);`